# Estimation to plot person-item map not feasible because items "have no 0-responses" in data matrix

Tags: r, matrix, plot

I am trying to create a person item map that organizes the questions from a dataset in order of difficulty. I am using the eRm package and the output should looks like follows:

[person-item map] (https://hansjoerg.me/post/2018-04-23-rasch-in-r-tutorial_files/figure-html/unnamed-chunk-3-1.png)

So one of the previous steps, before running the function that outputs the map, I have to fit the data set to have a matrix which is the object that the plotting functions uses to create the actual map, but I am having an error when creating that matrix

I have already tried to follow and review some documentation that might be useful if you want to have some extra-information:

```
    [Tutorial] https://hansjoerg.me/2018/04/23/rasch-in-r-tutorial/#plots
    [Ploting function] https://rdrr.io/rforge/eRm/man/plotPImap.html
    [Documentation] https://eeecon.uibk.ac.at/psychoco/2010/slides/Hatzinger.pdf
```

Now, this is the code that I am using. First, I install and load the respective libraries and the data:

```
    > library(eRm)
    > library(ltm)
    Loading required package: MASS
    Loading required package: msm
    Loading required package: polycor
    > library(difR)
```

Then I fit the PCM and generate the object of class Rm and here is the error:

> *the PCM function here is specific for polytomous data, if I use a different one the output says that I am not using a dichotomous dataset

```
    > res <- PCM(my.data)
    >Warning: 
    The following items have no 0-responses:
    AUT_10_04 AUN_07_01 AUN_07_02 AUN_09_01 AUN_10_01 AUT_11_01 AUT_17_01 
    AUT_20_03 CRE_05_02 CRE_07_04 CRE_10_01 CRE_16_02 EFEC_03_07 EFEC_05 
    EFEC_09_02 EFEC_16_03 EVA_02_01 EVA_07_01 EVA_12_02 EVA_15_06 FLX_04_01 
    ... [rest of items]
    >Responses are shifted such that lowest
    category is 0.
    Warning: 
    The following items do not have responses on
    each category:
    EFEC_03_07 LC_07_03 LC_11_05
    Estimation may not be feasible. Please check
    data matrix
```

I must clarify that all the dataset has a range from 1 to 5. Is a Likert polytomous dataset

Finally, I try to use the plot function and it does not have any output, the system just keep loading ad-infinitum with no answer

```
    >plotPImap(res, sorted=TRUE)
```

I would like to add the description of that particular function and the arguments:

```
    >PCM(X, W, se = TRUE, sum0 = TRUE, etaStart)
```

```
    #X  
    Input data matrix or data frame with item responses (starting from 0); 
    rows represent individuals, columns represent items. Missing values are 
    inserted as NA.

    #W  
    Design matrix for the PCM. If omitted, the function will compute W 
    automatically.

    #se 
    If TRUE, the standard errors are computed.

    #sum0   
    If TRUE, the parameters are normed to sum-0 by specifying an appropriate 
    W. 
    If FALSE, the first parameter is restricted to 0.

    #etaStart   
    A vector of starting values for the eta parameters can be specified. If                         
    missing, the 0-vector is used.
```

I do not understand why is necessary to have a score beginning from 0, I think that that what the error is trying to say but I don't understand quite well that output.

I highly appreciate any hint that you can provide me

Feel free to ask for any information that could be useful to reach the solution to this issue

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not caused by the fact that there are no items with 0-responses. The model automatically corrects this by centering the response scale categories on zero. (You'll notice that the PI-map that you linked to is centered on zero. Also, I believe the map you linked to is of dichotomous data. Polytomous data should include the scale categories on the PI-map, I believe.)

Without being able to see your data, it is impossible to know the exact cause though.

It may be that the model is not converging. That may be what this error was alluding to: `Estimation may not be feasible. Please check data matrix.` You could check by entering `> res` at the prompt. If the model was able to converge you should see something like:

```
Conditional log-likelihood: -2.23709 
Number of iterations: 27 
Number of parameters: 8
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your data contain answers with decimal numbers? I found the same error, I solved it by using `dplyr::dense_rank()` function:

```
df_ranked <- sapply(df_decimal_data, dense_rank)
```

Worked.